# Selector for getting all tags with a particular attribute and class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML in the following format

```
<g class="highcharts-series-group">
   ...
   <g class="highcharts-series highcharts-tracker" visibility="visible">
   </g>
   ...
   <g class="highcharts-series highcharts-tracker" visibility="hidden">
   </g>
   ...
</g>
```

I want to get all the elements that are within the `highcharts-series-group` class that have a class of `highcharts-series highcharts-tracker` and have `visibility` set to `visible`.

Doing this gives me too much as there are some elements that just have the `g.highcharts-series` class.

```
$('g.highcharts-series-group g.highcharts-series');
```

Doing this gives me nothing

```
$('g.highcharts-series-group g.highcharts-series .highcharts-series-tracker')
```

What is the correct selector and how do I also filter on visibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.highcharts-series-group .highcharts-series.highcharts-tracker[visibility="visible"]')`

This [visibility="visible"] is attribute selector

Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/jf7qx/5/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match an element that is a member of multiple classes, don't put a descendant combinator (a space) between the class selectors.

```
 g.highcharts-series.highcharts-series-tracker
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you all elements with `highcharts-series` and `highcharts-tracker` classes within the class `highcharts-series-group` which are also visible.

```
$(".highcharts-series-group .highcharts-series.highcharts-tracker:visible");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.highcharts-series-group .highcharts-series.highcharts-tracker[visibility="visible"]')
```

I've made you a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TkHHn/)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
var el = $('.highcharts-series.highcharts-tracker')
if( el.is(':visible') ) {
    el.css('background-color' , 'green');
    };
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BsM7U/1/)**